# Application doesn't appear on Application Loader

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, application-loader

I have an app for prerelease that is now in testFlight, I have 3 builds in it. Now I have a new update for the prerelease. Now whenever I go to Application Loader, I can't find my app. It gives me the other apps I made, but the app I really wanted to update won't appear. I already turned-off the testFlight for prerelease, still I can't find my app

Comment: Export the Signed ipa of your application and then click the choose button and then give it that ipa and it will work same

Comment: How can i do this :) sorry Im really not used here on iOS deployment

Comment: haven't you created ipa before .... ???? select the iOS device without connection device on the testing are and open Product menu and click Archive and it will as you to create ipa and then export the ipa as signed for the App Store

Comment: Oh is this the one that I make in the apple developer page?

Comment: no not that create it from the Xcode .....

Comment: Oh, I'm using Corona SDK, I think they create it for me, that's why i am not familiar to it

Comment: oh so i was telling you about native iOS you might be using other third party .... but all you have  to do is create an ipa and give it to application loader

Comment: It still doesn't show my app in itunes